# I don't know why I'm getting this error or index out of range. I'm using Python 3.0 in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, index-error

```
import random
from IPython.display import clear_output

dictionary = open("words_50000.txt","r")
dict_5000 = dictionary.readlines()
guess = random.choice(dict_5000).lower().strip('\n')
no_of_letters = len(guess)
game_str = ['-']*no_of_letters
only_length=[]

def word_guesser():
    only_length_words()
    print(dict_5000)


def only_length_words():
    for i in range(len(dict_5000)):
        if len(dict_5000[i].strip('\n'))!=no_of_letters:
            dict_5000.pop(i)    

word_guesser()
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        20             dict_5000.pop(i)
>        21 
>   ---> 22 word_guesser()
>
> in word_guesser()
>        11 
>        12 def word_guesser():
>   ---> 13     only_length_words()
>        14     print(dict_5000)
>        15
>
> in only_length_words()
>        17 def only_length_words():
>        18     for i in range(len(dict_5000)):
>   ---> 19         if len(dict_5000[i].strip('\n'))!=no_of_letters:
>        20             dict_5000.pop(i)
>        21
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: side note: use `with open` construct to open files otherwise you will always keep failing like now - you forgot to close file :); for question - change this`for i in range(len(dict_5000)):` to `for i in range(len(dict_5000)-1):`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: That too doesn't help me out. I edited my code the way you mentioned it. I'm now making the same changes in the code under my question. Please check it out.

Comment: somelist[:] = (x for x in somelist if determine(x))

This worked out for me. Thanks for your help. It was nice to have you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `pop()`, which mutilates the list, but you're also iterating over the list. So, let's say there is an element in the list that you popped out. Now, the length of the mutilated list is shorter then the original but the for loop will still try to iterate till the original length of the list and this is causing the `IndexError`.